# how to corectly plot grouped pandas series with string and numbers in different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

data looks like this:

[image]

```
 col1  col2
 1     med
 1     low
 1     high
 2     high
 3     low
 2     high
 3     low
```

there is two columns, i want to group col2 and count each item in col1, e.g. how many ones
and twos have 'maRali' feature.

used get_dummies to convert categorical variables to numeric, but while plotting get error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

here is the whole code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

data = data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\givi.jalaghania\.spyder-py3\07_maragebi.csv")

to_numeric = pd.get_dummies(data['riskiaobis done'])


ct = ['datvla']


# data.groupby(ct).agg('count').plot(kind = 'bar')


data.groupby(ct, to_numeric).size()
```

Comment: Problem is in `data.groupby(ct, to_numeric).size()` - what should do this code? How looks column `riskiaobis done` in sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I think here is possible use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(data['col1'], data['col2']).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: @jalaghania - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)